# open file in C and overwrite if it exists

Tags: c

I am working on a C program. I am not being able to open file and overwrite if it exists. I think the code is right, It is appending instead.

```
int in, out, append ,pid;
if (sc->infile)
{
    in = 1;
    printf("infile");
}
if (sc->outfile){
    out = 1;
    printf("outfile");
}
if (sc->append)
    append = 1;


if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    perror("some erro");
else if (pid == 0)
{
    /* Be childish */
    if (in)
    {

        int fd0 = open(sc->infile, O_RDONLY);
        dup2(fd0, STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd0);
    }

    if (out)
    {
        printf("outfile detece");
        int fd1;
        if (append)
             fd1 = open(sc->outfile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0666);
        else

            fd1 = open(sc->outfile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT , 0666);;
        dup2(fd1, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd1);
    }

    execvp(sc->argv[sc->cmdStart[0]], &(sc->argv[sc->cmdStart[0]])); 
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec\n" );
    exit(1);
}
else
{
/* Be parental */
    wait(0);
}
```

Could someone help on this. I have tried a lot to fix this.

Comment: The code definitely overwrites an existing file.

Comment: It appends because you didn't specify `O_TRUNC`. Try `outputFd = open(sc->outfile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);`. This is equivalent to `outputFd = creat(c->outfile, 0666);`.

Comment: "Append" isn't quite the right word; with neither `O_TRUNC` nor `O_APPEND`, the file position starts at the beginning of the file, and you can overwrite a prefix (with another string of the same length).

Comment: hi @alvits i updated my qsn with code, could you please take a look

Comment: @Sulavk are you bounded to Unix/Linux/Mac? You could use `fopen("filename", 'r')` you know

Comment: @GRC yes, i am bounded to linux /unix

Comment: How have you demonstrated that your code did not use the `open()` with `O_APPEND`?  You've not shown the definition of `sc`, or how it is initialized.  Given the described behaviour of appending, it is plausible to guess that you have `sc->append` set, so you have `O_APPEND`.  Please re-read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and provide one.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

`outputFd = open(sc->outfile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT , 0666);`

Seems correct, just make sure `sc->outfile` is correct. Have you printed return value of `open()` or what `perror("open()")` says.

From the manual page of `open`

> Return Value
>
> open() and creat() return the new file descriptor, or -1 if an error
>   occurred (in which case, errno is set appropriately).

Also print the `errno`. For example

```
int outputFd;
outputFd = open(sc->outfile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT , 0666);
if(outputFd == -1) {
    /* Error handling */
}
```

*It is appending instead ?*  No, it's not possible with the code snapshot you mentioned. If you could have used `O_APPEND`.

Comment: can you please check my code, I tried but still getting the same result. It is not overwriting,

Comment: what is `sc`  @Sulavk ?

Answer (score 0):

`in`,`out`,`append` are not initialized to zero so this will cause issues.

Change the declaration line to be

```
int in = 0, out = 0, append = 0, pid;
```